# Complexity of projected model counting

Tags: counting-complexity

Counting the models of propositional quantifier-free formulas, #SAT, is #P-complete (under parsimonious reductions).

I was wondering about the complexity of counting the models of existentially quantified formulas (∃x<sub>1</sub>…x<sub>n</sub> P), a problem known as *projected model counting*.

It's obviously #P-hard, obviously in PSPACE, and… I don't see to find anything in the literature.

Comment: Well, the problem is clearly #NP-complete. #NP is (along with all of $\mathrm{\#P^{ModPH}}$) included in $\mathrm{FP^{\#P[1]}}$; in fact, it is included in its subclass MP (see [The Power of the Middle Bit of a #P Function](https://doi.org/10.1006/jcss.1995.1036)), or rather, the function version of this class.

Comment: Right about #NP-complete, but are there known equalities of classes there?

Comment: I don’t know of equalities as such, but as I wrote, this class is known to be just a tiny bit above #P: you can compute any #NP function by computing a #P function and throwing away a bunch of low-order and high-order bits. That’s quite a tight upper bound. Why do you need equalities?

Comment: Actually I don't. Thanks for the references.